# Laserscan bag to film

Tags: opencv, rosbag, pcl, bagfiles, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

i'm looking for a method to automatically generate films from laserscan bags.
Important is that it's also possible to set the camera perspective.

So far i've been thinking about extracting PCD files, extracting images from the PCD file and stringing them together. But i didn't find any possibility to use my own camera perspective for taking the picture.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Except writing a hole new engine...
Does OpenCV maybe offer some useful methods for that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51881/laserscan-bag-to-film/) by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 230 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd try to do this with rviz. You could set camera views there (I'm not sure if it's possible programmatically).

To record this, I'd just do screencaps.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1